# AWS Virtual Machine Https for port other than 443

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, virtual-machine

I want to change https port for something else.
Is it possible in aws ec2 ?
In inbound rules for security group associated with vm instance, port field is disabled
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to open the port for HTTPS and it's not 443, then don't add it as HTTPS but just add a "Custom TCP" rule for the desired port. It will work.