# How to deploy express.js app to Amazon EC2 and have it available from HTTPS without domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

The idea is to fetch api in **expressjs** deployed to **Amazon EC2**.
The problem is that Inbound rules don't allow to create connection for `HTTPS` on other ports than `443`.

The solution with creating Custom TCP rule and removing HTTPS rule (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453119/aws-virtual-machine-https-for-port-other-than-443)) did not work for me.

I tried to install Load Balancer but had no luck because it asks for certificate which was impossible to release without domain name. Is it possible to get certificate for Amazon's generated **Public IPv4 DNS**?

After that, I have tried to install **NGINX** server for reverse proxy as it was described here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7

It did work but only for **HTTP**, because I could not release Let's Encrypt certificate for Amazon's **Public IPv4 DNS**.
When I tried to do it via **certbot** with `sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d <subdomain>.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

```
An unexpected error occurred:
The server will not issue certificates for the identifier :: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for "<subdomain>.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com": The ACME server refuses to issue a certificate for this domain name, because it is forbidden by policy
```

Then I tried to release for IP address, but:

```
Requested name <my_ip_address> is an IP address. The Let's Encrypt certificate authority will not issue certificates for a bare IP address.
```

So, is there a way to have a **expressjs** app on **Amazon EC2** with **HTTPS** without registered domain name?
I want to have api there which I can fetch from other https website. Any suggestion?

Comment: Its not possibile. SSL certificates are associated with domain names, not ip addresses.

Comment: what about Amazon's Public IPv4 DNS?

Comment: No. For a valid public ssl certificate you must have your own domain.

Comment: Just a note that the default security group rule for HTTPS doesn't automatically enable HTTPS. It's simply an easy way to open the 443 port that's normally used for HTTPS traffic. You still have to set up an SSL certificate for it to work properly.